# Excel invokes .NET automation server from two different AppDomains?

Tags: .net, excel, com, vsto, appdomain

I have an Excel plug-in (written in C#) with a static variable that is at the heart of a singleton data cache:

```
static DataCache _instance;
```

This is accessed via three different code paths:

1. Event handlers on a VSTO ribbon-bar initialize the instance, and also read it for display in helper dialogs
2. An RTD server (a class that is declared [ComVisible] and implements the IRtdServer interface) utilizes the data for RTD formulas
3. A set of automation calls (implemented in another class that is declared [ComVisible]) also operate on the data.  These are called by way of VBA code that is invoked when buttons on the Excel worksheet are clicked.

EDIT (#3):

Depending on the order in which these code paths are first invoked, I find that my code runs in two separate AppDomains.

All access from the ribbon-bar event handlers occurs in an AppDomain called "MyPlugIn.vsto".  If this is the FIRST access to my COM object, then all subsequent calls (including RTD calls) occur in the same AppDomain.

However if the FIRST access is via the RTD interface, then that call and all subsequent RTD calls occur in an AppDomain called "DefaultDomain".  (This happens when loading a saved document with embedded RTD formulas.)  Subsequent calls to initialize and manipulate the DataCache via the toolbar still occur in the "MyPlugIn.vsto" AppDomain.  This means that the RTD formulas always run as if the DataCache were not initialized (since the static variable set in one AppDomain remains uninitialized in the other).

It appears that Excel or the VSTO is creating an AppDomain when VSTO initializes.  Objects created via COM interop before this initialization land in the default AppDomain, while objects created afterwards land in the VSTO AppDomain.

How can I ensure that the same DataCache instance is utilized, no matter which AppDomain my RTD server object gets created in?

Comment: What do you mean 'my singleton object is not properly shared'? Is it just the initialization of the object, as @mhttk suggests, or are you claiming that different threads see different state in that variable (which seems very odd), or something else?

Comment: @Rory -- in one thread, _instance gets initialized.  In subsequent calls from that same thread, it is still initialized as expected.  However when another thread tries to access it (several minutes later -- this is not a timing issue) it is null and must be re-initialized for use by that thread.

Comment: That's pretty weird isn't it? In my experience of .NET COM interop (with Internet Explorer which is similar but obviously different), that doesn't happen. Is that a normal thing with COM apartments? Are you sure the calls are within the same process?

Comment: @Rory -- yes, it is very weird, and does not seem to comply with what I find in the documentation about COM interop.  I think I've only got a single process running, but I'm starting to wonder if Excel is somehow getting me two AppDomains, or perhaps two side-by-side runtime versions.  I'll keep looking...

Comment: How about: Try using `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id` and `Thread.GetDomainId()` within the debugger to see if the calls are coming in on the same process & app domain. And write a message out on DataCache.Dispose() so you can see when it's disposed.

Comment: Another thought - can you freeze one thread in the debugger and then make another call to your plug-in, so you have two threads going through your code at once? That might let you see a bit more in the debugger about what's going on. 
Also I believe that there's always just a single value for a static field, regardless of AppDomains. Maybe it's possible for the Assembly to be unloaded, in which case the value would be lost, but you're saying you see two independent non-null values for the field, which I don't think is possible. Unless there's separate versions of the CLR loaded?

Comment: I've confirmed that there are two different AppDomains in play;  I'll update the question with details.

Comment: This was a great post. In process explorer I can see that my VSTO addin is doing the same thing: creating a Default AppDomain and a myplugin.vsto AppDomain. Is there anyway for me to take a look at which AppDomain certain COM objects are loaded into? Either with a debugger and source code or with a tool like process explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your static variable is certainly not shared between AppDomains, so what you are seeing is as expected, given the different AppDomains.

I think it works like this:

The VSTO add-in runs in its own AppDomain. If the COM class factory for your cache object (or RTD server) is created from within that AppDomain, it will be loaded into the calling AppDomain. Subsequent access to that COM class will find it already loaded into the process, and use the existing instance.

However, if the first activation is triggered by Excel itself, e.g. by an RTD call, the .NET implemented COM object will be loaded into the default AppDomain of the process. You have no control over this part of the loading process unless you make an unmanaged shim, since 'your code' is not running when the loading happens.

Some suggestions off the top of my head:

1. Make some wrapper functions for the RTD calls which are exposed from your .NET add-in. This way, you can ensure the RTD class is loaded before calling Excel's Application.RTD to do the real RTD setup.
2. Make the access from the RTD server to the actual cache through user-defined functions - this way Excel will call into the AppDomain that has the real cache, even if it is not the current AppDomain where the RTD server lives.
3. Try to get hold of the Add-In object via Application.AddIns.... there is a way to get the actual add-in COM object, and use some interface on it to get to the cache...
4. Make an unmanaged shim (search the web for "COM shim wizard") for your RTD server. Somehow figure out how to get your VSTO AppDomain loaded, and then load the RTD server into that AppDomain.
5. See if there is a way to get the VSTO add-in loaded into the default AppDomain. I don't know, but perhaps there is a flag or switch that tells the "Microsoft Office Systems loader" (or whatever that part is called now) not to create the isolated AppDomain.
6. The right answer: use [Excel-Dna](http://exceldna.codeplex.com) (disclaimer: I'm the developer). It supports Ribbons, RTD and UDFs in your managed add-in, with no registration needed, and everything gets put into your add-ins AppDomain. It's free, but it will take some time and effort to port your stuff - RTD is trivial, but if you use a lot of the VSTO helper objects for the Ribbon and sheet access (tables etc.), you'll need to think about it a bit.

I hope this gives you some ideas.

--Govert--

Comment: I have the exact same issue as the original poster: my addin loads in AppDomain1, then when Excel encounters a cell with `=RTD` and my progid, it instantiates _another_ AppDomain2 where of course none of the state I've been keeping around can be found.
I've tried to instantiate (using .NET Activator) my RTD Server on startup which works and type is instantiated in my assembly but Excel _still_ creates another assembly. I'm not sure how I would go about your proposals 1/2/3 - would taking a look at your Excel-Dna project help in some way (where should I look)? Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

first, you may want to declare your instance as:

```
static DataCache _instance = new DataCache();
```

this way (not the only one for sure), you know _instance is generated thread safe. There is much coverage on the topic for thread safe singletons, but this seems one of the simplest solutions.

The second thing may be you want to try using is a structure like

```
Lock (_lockObject)
{
...
}
```

for both reads and writes. This will make your reads and writes safe from different threads.

Finally, but this is pure speculation, you can try by creating a separate object for your COM calls that resides in a STA and accesses your library.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm sorry, this does not address my problem.  I have edited the  question to clarify that several minutes pass between when one thread initializes the instance and other thread attempts to use it.  This is not a thread synchronization issue, it's something about how the .NET/COM implementation works.